# Экранирование знака ? в preg_match

Tags: php

Есть следующая функция:

```
$currentURI = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') . '/';        
$currentURI = preg_replace('~page=[0-9]+~', '', $currentURI);
```

Вопрос: как правильно написать следующее регулярное выражение:

```
$currentURI = preg_replace('~/?page=[0-9]+~', '', $currentURI);
```

Где `/?` - содержание строки, а не синтаксис регулярного выражения? Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: обратным слешем \/\?

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете экранировать символы в регулярных выражениях с помощью обратного слэша: `~/\?page=[0-9]+~`. Таким образом эти символы будут восприниматься как самые обычные символы, а не специальные символы.

Comment: внутри ~ можно и так /\?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, спасибо, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для экранирования спецсимволов в рег.выражениях можно использовать [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php)

```
$str = preg_quote("/?page=", '~'); // '/\?page='
$currentURI = preg_replace("~{$str}\d+~", '', $currentURI);
```

---

В Вашем случае, вероятно, имеет смысл более конкретно описать то, что Вам нужно.
Например:

```
$currentURI = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: использование preg_quote() имеет смысл для динамических шаблонов. Для экранирования одного-двух символов использовать эту  функцию тоже можно, но есть ли смысл палить из пушки по воробьям? ☺

Comment: Во первых, почему бы и нет, а во вторых, это просто альтернативный ответ. Ответ про backslash уже был.

Answer (score 1):

> В качестве альтернативного ответа можно добавить, что в регулярных выражениях PCRE *(т. е. в PHP)* и Perl поддерживается специальная последовательность **\Q…\E**, внутри которой игнорируются все метасимволы *(разумеется, кроме закрывающего \Е)*.
>
> Кроме этого, ещё есть возможность преобразования метасимволов в литералы *(т.е., в обычный текст)* с помощью символьного класса **[…]**, но в этом случае есть пара исключений.
>
> Во первых, символ *крышка* **^**, записанный сразу после открывающей квадратной скобки символьного класса **[^**, так и останется метасимволом, означающим инвертирование последовательности символов текущего символьного класса. Если нужно использовать *крышку* в качестве литерала, достаточно записать её в любой другой позиции *(но не в первой)*. Например этот шаблон **'~[?^]~'** будет соответствовать символам **?** или **^**, а вот этот **'~[^?]~'** будет соответствовать одному любому символу, кроме символа **?**.
>
> Во вторых, символ *тире* **-**, записанный между литералами символьного класса, не будет соответствовать символу *тире*. Для преобразования тире из метасимвола в литерал, нужно записать его вначале или в конце символьного класса. Например такая запись **'~[-^?]~'** будет соответствовать одному из трёх символов в этой позиции: тире, крышке, или вопросительному знаку.
>
> Что касается прямого слэша **/** - он не относится к группе метасимволов, и экранирования требует только в том случае, если он является ограничителем шаблона регулярного выражения. Но в таких случаях удобнее заменить символ ограничителя на любой другой, подходящий для текущего шаблона.